# Static strings localization issue in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, localization, refactoring

Currently, I have a file called Messages which is a class with several static strings:

```
public class Messages {
    public static final String MESSAGE_1 = "Message one";
    public static final String MESSAGE_2 = "Message two";
    ...
}
```

What is the best way to refactor this implementation in order to support multiple languages? The name of the string should remain the same, but the value should change according to the locale string I pass. Not sure how to approach the implementation.

Comment: One of the way will be to do a db read depending on localization.

Comment: @yogidilip I do not use a database at the moment, and I do not wish to use one. The implementation should be done on file level.

Comment: You need a suitable data structure behind it. ``Map``, ``enum``, a database, a localization file...

Comment: Have a look at `ResourceBundle` :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create separate files under resources folder with name as 
   `messages_<locale>.properties` for example messages_de_DE.properties
   for germany and so on.
2. In these files put the key value pair as you put in any properties file with the text in the local of the filaname
3. And create a bean like this.

   ```
   @Configuration
   class InternationalizationConfig {

   @Bean
   public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
       SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
       slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
       return slr;
   }
   @Bean
   public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
       ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
       messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
       messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600);
       return messageSource;
   }
   ```

   }

Whereever you want to put locale specific string just autowire MessageSource

```
@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;
 messageSource.getMessage(....)
```

Comment: messageSource.getMessage("test_message", null, Locale.ENGLISH)

I created a file under resources/messages/messages.en.properties and changed the classpath to classpath:messages/messages however I can't get this solution to work. What's the issue?

Comment: what do you get when you do this `messageSource.getMessage("test_message", null, Locale.ENGLISH` . I hope you have test_message key in messages.en.properties

Comment: No message found under code 'test_message'. The entry is inside the messages.en property

Comment: did you try to putting directly unders resources?

Comment: The issue was the file naming, `messages.<locale>.properties` should be `messages_<locale>.properties`